# Altering a column and cancelling the alter greatly improves SQL performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

We have a table that has roughly 5.5 million rows. We use Entity Framework and run a query on this table and get our row of interest based on 2 columns. One FK column that has an index (`Type`) and another column (`ObjectId`) that is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` that cannot have an index.

We experienced timeouts in our system. As a proof of concept I was going to change the `ObjectId` column to a fixed length so I could add an index.

I execute an alter statement . . .

```
ALTER TABLE Audit.Changes 
    ALTER COLUMN ObjectId VARCHAR(50) NULL
```

After 2 seconds or 2 minutes, I cancel the statement, it has NOT fully executed.

I re-run my test and the query starts to run without any timeout issue.

NOTE: I have tried to run `UPDATE STATISTICS` without an improvement.

NOTE: If I restore a backup, problem comes back, and I can consistently fix it by running the alter and cancelling it.

My question: what is SQL Server invalidating under the hood or what is it doing where triggering a change on the column or cancelling an alteration to the table would cause the timeout to go away? Is there a direct command I can use to instead of running the statement and a cancel.

Comment: Could be invalidating the query plans referencing this table.  You can track the plans over time and force a good one if necessary using the Query Store. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'd suggest you do a update statistics with full scan, as your current scenario (i.e. trying to alter a column and then cancel the alter action) will very likely 1. cause the next run query plan recompiled and/or 2. cause the statistics on this column totally refreshed. That's why I suggest you to do a stats update with full scan, which should give you the same benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it has read a bunch of pages into the buffer pool and is now running with a "hot" cache. Do your cancelled query thing, test performance, then

```
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
```

And test again. Fast or slow?